# PHImageManager get image metadata

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

I'm currently updating a project from Assets framework to the Photos framework.

I am a bit stuck at a place where I have to get the metadata for images while they are kept in iCloud.

My current solution:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeFastFormat;
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:self.asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    // Here I parse the info which serves to me as sufficient metadata.
}];
```

However this still causes a download of the image data, which in large folders will be a problem. Is there any way that would allow me to request **only** the metadata of an image?

Comment: I don't think so. It's not an unreasonable use case, so I suggest filing an enhancement request with Apple.